# Javascript Comparision expression

Tags: javascript, arrays, equality

I am confused about javascript comparison. let's say :

```
var array1 = [1,2,3];
var array2 = [1,2,3];

array1 == array2 ; 
false // why false ? 

array1 === array2;
false // also why false?
```

Can anyone explain this to me clearly? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> "Objects, arrays, and functions are
>   compared by reference."

-- [O'Reilly's JavaScript: The Definitive Guide](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch05_04.htm)

In your case `array1` is a reference to a different Array than `array2`.

[See here for a way to compare Arrays.](http://www.breakingpar.com/bkp/home.nsf/0/87256B280015193F87256BFB0077DFFD)

Answer (score 4):

They are false because you are comparing two different Array instances. It will only be true if they are actually references to the *same* instance.

```
var array1 = [1,2,3];
var array2 = array1;

array1 == array2 ; // true
```

To compare their content, you need to compare each item individually. Something like this, though this doesn't look any deeper than the one level.

```
var array1 = [1,2,3];
var array2 = [1,2,3];

function compareArrays(a1,a2) { 
    var len = a1.length;
    if( len !== a2.length )
        return false;
    while( len-- ) {
        if( a1[ len ] !== a2[ len ] ) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

compareArrays( array1, array2 ); // true
```